# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting

**undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass**

When I made my custom validation before create new data table.
This is my code in the the controller, everything works fine before the validation method trigger.

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'

  before_action :admin_logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy,:edit,:update]
  before_action :admin_correct_user, only:[:destroy,:update,:edit]
  before_action :permanent_event_check, only:[:create,:update]

  def list

  end

  def create
    @activity = admin_current_user.activities.build(activity_param)
    if @activity.save
      flash[:success] = "Activity Created!"
      redirect_to admin_dashboard_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def new
    @activity = Activity.new
  end

  private

  def activity_param
    params.require(:activity).permit(:name,:details,:start_at,:end_at,
                                     :activity_image01_url,:activity_image02_url,:activity_image03_url,
                                     :youtube_url,:capacity,:booking_status,:rules,:apply_details,
                                     :payment_price,:payment_need,:avaliable,:rating,:temple_id)
  end

  def admin_correct_user
    @activity = admin_current_user.activities.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to admin_dashboard_url if @activity.nil?
  end

  def permanent_event_check
    param_activity = params[:activity]

    if param_activity[:permanent] == "false"
      if param_activity[:start_at] == "" || param_activity[:end_at] == ""
        @activity.errors[:base] << "You can't leave start and end date blank with Permanent Event"
        return false
      end
    end

  end

end
```

And this line.

```
@activity.errors[:base] << "You can't leave start and end date blank with Permanent Event"
```

I got the error from this line.

How to fix this?
Thanks!

******* add model file after moving validation

This is my model after i tried to move my validation but it seems like nothing in return from @activity

```
validate :permanent_event_check
private

  def permanent_event_check
    param_activity = @activity

    if param_activity.permanent == "false"
      if param_activity.start_at == "" || param_activity.end_at == ""
        @activity.errors[:base] << "You can't leave start and end date blank with Permanent Event"
        return false
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you add the Rails server full stacktrace? I know the reason, but just want to confirm it once.

Comment: before action executes before the specified methods... `@activity` in uninitialized just put this line `@activity = admin_current_user.activities.find(whatever you'll use to find activity when updating) || admin_current_user.activities.build(activity_param)` just after `param_activity = params[:activity]`

Comment: My guess is you hit the `create` action and got the error. Because `@activity` is initialized inside the create, but your error code is triggering before the `create` action is being performed, that is why `@activity` is nil.

Comment: And my STRONG suggestion is to create a custom validation to do the check. Controller is not the correct place. Move your code in the model, or inside the validator directory. Your approach to the problem is wrong, so fix the approach, your problem will be solved.

Comment: @ArupRakshit is right... you should not do validations inside controller..

Comment: How can i move all these things to the model?

Comment: @Minato i tried to move the method to model but seems still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From your `before_action` blocks:

```
before_action :admin_logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy,:edit,:update]
before_action :admin_correct_user, only:[:destroy,:update,:edit]
before_action :permanent_event_check, only:[:create,:update]
```

You have the `admin_correct_user` which is setting `@activity` before you have `permanent_event_check` from where you are adding the error.

However, `admin_correct_user` only triggers for the actions: `[:destroy,:update,:edit]` while `permanent_event_check` triggers for `create` and `update`.

The Implication of this is that for the `create` action, the order of events in your controller is: `admin_logged_in_user` (which is probably a validation) -> `permanent_event_check` (trying to add errors). Notice that the other action (`admin_correct_user`) which was meant to set `@activity` was skipped.

Therefore... for the `create` action especially, as at the point where you are trying to add the error, there is no object named `@activity`.

> `@activity` is Nil

So... the reason for the error.

**To fix it:**

Ensure to build the `@activity` object before trying to access it(for validation or for any other thing).

Arup's suggestion of moving the validation into your model is a great one!

**To Move it to the model:**

```
#activity.rb:
validate :right_event

def right_event
  #check validity, and add custom error here
  unless permanent
    errors.add(:permanent, "You can't leave start and end date blank...") unless self.start_at and self.end_at
  end
end
```

Comment: I cannot do this because my "admin_correct_user" method use params[:id] to identify the correct activity but for now i dont have that in side create

Comment: ah... yes. so... You can then have another method to build the `@activity` object from params before adding the error. Or... basically, move the validation into your model as suggested by Arup. Basically: what you want is to build `@activity` before trying to access it. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: How can i get the params value inside the model?

Comment: Inside the model, all param values would have become the attributes of the new instance `@activity`... as built from your create action: `@activity = admin_current_user.activities.build(activity_param)`

Comment: I tried to get the value from @activity but nothing in return.So confused

Comment: How? did you see my example in the answer? can you show how you are going about it?